# Python: Condensing code into nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I need to print this code using nested for-loops. I see the pattern within my code, but am unsure how to condense it. It seems really simple, but it's not quite clicking yet for me. The result should look like this:

```
01234
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

My code prints this, but no nested loops are involved and its kind of lengthy. Any help condensing it?

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print(i,end='')
print()
for i in range(1,6):
    print(i,end='')
print()
for i in range(2,7):
    print(i,end='')
print()
for i in range(3,8):
    print(i,end='')
print()
for i in range(4,9):
    print(i,end='')
print()
for i in range(5,10):
    print(i,end='')
print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Also check out [ask]. What have you already tried? What's the pattern you see? Do you know how to get that pattern into code? If not, how would you write out the steps on paper? I'm happy Mark posted a good answer for you, but I want to help you learn how to use this site better and how to work through problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that each set of numbers you print is `1` plus the previous group. So if you make an outer loop that increases by one, you can add that to the numbers in the inner loop. There are a few ways to do this, but this should be pretty clear:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(5):
        print(j+i, end='')
    print()
```

printing:

```
01234
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

For a different take, consider that the inner loop is just a range starting at increasing starting numbers. You can print a range in python by spreading it out into the print function with `*`. This, plus `sep=''` allow you to print the ranges in a single for loop by creating an range than starts at the increasing indices of the loop:

```
rows = 6
cols = 5

for i in range(rows):
    print(*range(i, i+cols), sep='')

# prints the same thing as the code above
```

Answer (score 0):

Two-tier loops can solve your problem. The outer one traverses for the `start_index` of each output sequence, and the inner one describes the rule how to generate each output sequence from the `start_index`.

So try this:

```py
start, end = 0, 6
output_len, inner_step = 5, 1
for start_index in range(start, end):
  output_seq = ""
  for o in range(start_index, start_index+output_len, inner_step):
    output_seq += str(o)
  print(output_seq)
```

Edit: `inner_step` can be omitted, because the default `step` of `range` is 1. I wrote it to emphasize we can change it for more general `rule`.

Comment: Maybe this is unnecessary, but you could simplify the inner part significantly by having `print()` do the heavy lifting: `output_seq = range(start_index, start_index+output_len); print(*output_seq, sep='')`

Comment: In this simple inner rule, inner loop can be replaced with single `print`.  I try to answer the general principle and ignore some optimization details. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is something you want.

```
def pattern_creator(number_of_loops: int, start_pattern: str) -> None: 
    for loop in range(number_of_loops):
        print(''.join([str(int(x)+loop) for x in start_pattern]))

pattern_creator(number_of_loops=6, start_pattern='01234')
```

Comment: OP's starting from ints, so why are you using a string? I realize this gets the right result, but it doesn't seem to be what they're looking for.

Comment: @wjandrea I agree with it partially. The start of the printed list starts with `01234` which doesn't look like an int I assume.

Comment: Eh? It's 5 ints concatenated together

Comment: ohhh. yeah you are right!